# How to delete every files in a http directory programatically

Tags: c#, .net

I need to delete all the files in a virtual directory on the remote web server programatically. How to do this task?

Comment: Is this your web server?

Comment: Do you mean from a web app or from a standalone .NET app? What kind of access do you have?

Comment: from a standard .net app. I have fill permission of the folder on web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filezilla for acessing your remote server. This is a ftp client tool for free of cost. You keying your host ftp address and then you can remove the files.

-saligh

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the remote machine.  Go to the directory and remove it.  Or edit the server configuration to not serve up the directory.